# get full value from value from table in a web page using Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, c#-4.0

I am trying to get the full value of the "Transaction and get url" using the Html Agility Pack. when i inspect the html source using google i am able to see the full transaction id with a url. My question is how do i get the full value of all Transaction and the url associated with them.

here is the url of the site: http://explorer.litecoin.net/address/LeDGemnpqQjrK8v1s5HZKaDgjgDKQ2MYiK

example of date being brought back "TransactionBlockApprox. TimeAmountBalanceCurrency
                                    5130f066e0...4682752013-11-28 09:14:170.30.3LTC"

```
protected void Page_Load(string address)
    {
        string Url = address;
        HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
        HtmlDocument doc = web.Load(Url);

        string wallet = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/div/div/table")[0].InnerText[0].InnerText;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some times you have to do things manually you cant get the full link directly since javascript is used, to get it you have to manipulate the innerhtml of the td element which contains the href and get whats between the double qutations, and its always better to represent the data as objects such as

```
 public class data
    {
        public itemWithlink Transaction { get; set; }
        public itemWithlink Block { get; set; }
        public itemWithlink ApproxTime { get; set; }
        public itemWithlink Amount { get; set; }
        public itemWithlink Balance { get; set; }
        public itemWithlink Currency { get; set; }
    }

    public class itemWithlink
    {
        public string numberOrname { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
    }
```

and to produce a list of your table with link value to be set as long as its found

```
var list = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table/tr").
           Skip(1).
           Select(tr => tr.Elements("td").
           Select(td => new itemWithlink() { 
           numberOrname = td.InnerText, link = td.InnerHtml.Contains("href") ?
           td.InnerHtml.Substring(td.InnerHtml.IndexOf("\""), td.InnerHtml.LastIndexOf("\""))
           .Replace("..",@"http://explorer.litecoin.net/") : null })
           .ToArray())
           .Select(row => new data() { Transaction = row[0], Block = row[1], ApproxTime = row[2], Amount = row[3],  Balance = row[4] , Currency = row[5]  }).ToList();
```

Comment: this looks like it will work!!! question if i am doing data binding how can i implement this

Comment: @Robert you will have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for each property and of course you need backing fields and a custom item template depending on the control you are using